# Select next rows from subquery result

Tags: mysql

It was easy to find a solution for getting the next row when having ONE id:

```
SELECT MIN(id) FROM foo WHERE id > ?
```

But what if I would like to have the next ids (plural) from a subquery result? E.g.:

```
SELECT id FROM foo WHERE property > 0
```

This query will return a certain amount of ids, e.g.: `1, 2, 4, 6`. Lets say, the row with id `3` has already been deleted, and the property of row `5` is < 0.

So what I want is a result like this: `2, 4, 5, 7`.

The problem is, that I can't combine these two queries, because the later one returns more than one row, obviously.

How am I able to get all next ids from a subquery? Is it possible with a single query or will I need to use procedures?

Comment: What's the practical use of this query? ID numbers are usually arbitrary. This seems more like a puzzle than a real-world programming problem.

Comment: The reason for that is that I'm having only 2000 rows, but about 20 properties and > 2000000 combinations of properties that I want to check, so I need to minimize query calls. A simplified example for what I am trying to achieve: get the avg °C where it was raining the day before.

Comment: Ahh, it's not really IDs you're interested in, it's a column like `date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading this right you want a query that will work the same as:

```
SELECT MIN(id) FROM foo WHERE id > ?
```

but for multiple ids. So you get the next existing id in sequence for a given list of ids. That does seem a little strange, I have a feeling that the functionality you're trying to achieve can probably do implemented in a different way. I'm also assuming that there's a good reason why you can't just get the entire table and find the correct ids in whatever code is using the data.

Having said that, yes it can be done. You already have the query that gets the correct 'next' id, so what you can do is join the table against itself to create a table with two id columns, one is the original id and the other is the 'next' id. Then you can filter that table against the list of original ids you have and return the other id. Like that:

```
SELECT f1.id AS id
    FROM foo f1, foo f2
    WHERE f1.id = 
        ( SELECT MIN( f3.id ) FROM foo f3 WHERE f3.id > f2.id ) 
    AND f2.id IN ( 1, 2, 4, 6 )
;
```

On my system that returns 2, 4, 5, 7 if I setup my table as you describe (no id 3, 5 and 7 have property <= 0).

That query may not be the fastest over a large amount of data.

I think that's what you want to do, as **developerCK** says you can use `GROUP_CONCAT` if you need to feed the results of the `property > 0` query into this query. But if that's what you want to do you can skip the middle man and combine the queries like this:

```
SELECT f1.id AS id
    FROM foo f1, foo f2
    WHERE f1.id = 
        ( SELECT MIN( f3.id ) FROM foo f3 WHERE f3.id > f2.id ) 
    AND f2.property > 0
;
```

Comment: Thanks SpaceDog, this is exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunately the whole approach turned out to be getting too slow for my needs. Nevertheless, your answer is correct and hereby accepted :)

Answer (score -1):

I am still not clear about your query, but what i understand is,
this  function will help you,

```
GROUP_CONCAT()
```

it will create a comma separated list for all rows for a particular column so that you can get it with your first query.
for more detail about this pls

visit:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

or

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php

Comment: What does GROUP_CONCAT have to do with selecting the next row after the one that matches a criteria?

Comment: i was not clear about question , but comma separated list can be get through this function in a single row.

Comment: He's not asking how to get a comma separated list. That was just the way he listed the IDs he wants in the result.

Comment: Anyone, please give @developerCK an award?